# How to prevent appstore link from opening in the Appstore app?

Tags: ios, webview

I made simple app just for testing.
it simply has a webview on it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView
```

in viewDidLoad()

```
let url = NSURL (string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/keynote/id361285480")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)
```

the string "https://www.google.com" works right on both Simulator and Device opened in my webview.

So, i tested on my device, but as soos as I run it, it opens the Appstore app taking me to the Keynote app's page.
And in my app, the page is total white.

I simply want to see the webpage in my webview.
What should I do?

Comment: Read your code again!

Comment: @user523234 a little hint would be nicer

Comment: Sorry mate, I misread the question!